# How to fix this 'required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate' error?

Tags: swift, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play sound with local file and online URL.
But I got an error and could not find the reason. I searched but could not find the solution. 
Here is my error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false:
>   format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'

Here is my code:

```
var globalPlayer = AVPlayer()
let asset = AVURLAsset.init(url: url, options: nil)
let item = AVPlayerItem.init(asset: asset)
globalPlayer = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: item)
globalPlayer.volume = 1
globalPlayer.play()
```

Please help me, thank you so much!

Comment: May be the sample rate of your sources is not supported by the device? Have you tried with different sources?

Comment: That's an unusual error to get with an `AVPlayer`. Can you share a url to the audio file?

Comment: Yannick, oh, maybe you are right, my code work but sometime it crash, not every time, I will check the sources. Thank for your sugguestion.

Comment: @Fistman: 
let silenceAudioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo_sound ", ofType: "mp3")
I think: the problem would not be url

Answer (score 0):

my code looks like this simple and work

```
class Player{
var avplayer : AVPlayer?;

function play(){ 
    self.avplayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
    self.avplayer?.volume = 1.0
    self.avplayer?.play()
}

}
```